# Removing website from profile on one site and saving and copying changes to all SE does not propagate the removal

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-edit

For my existing SE account profiles, I'm unable to see the removal of a website getting propagated to the other site profiles.  I had to go in and remove them one by one.  My [main SE profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1199112/saad-shakil) is still showing that link, though I'm not sure how to remove it from that specific profile.

Is this by design - am I missing something here? Or, is this a bug?

Comment: I still see that website linked on some of your profiles (this one and SO are the ones I checked). Is that intentional? Your post suggests that you removed it on each site individually already.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I removed it from my SO profile individually as well.  Though I expected upon removing the URL (which happens to be the same across all my profiles) and clicking the second button with text "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities" that all URLs be removed from all of my profiles.  I can see that one may want different website URLs on different profiles, so propagating removal from one to all may not be a good idea. I'm not currently sure which it is - is the URL shared among all profiles, or unique to each - appears to be the latter, with what I've seen so far.

Comment: "Save and copy to all profiles" *should* do just that - copy whatever you have to all other sites without skipping fields. I don't have the code in front of me right now, so I'm just trying to figure out what you did (since you said you removed the URL on each site individually as well, but it's still there?) so that I have a better idea of how to (try to) reproduce this later.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Recently I joined worldbuilding.stackexchenge. I'm guessing that the profile for that took information from my main SE or SO profile, as the URL appeared there as well. After you pointed out that my SO profile still had the URL, I removed it from that and again clicked the 2nd button, as I did so before when I removed the URL from them individually (shouldn't have had to do this, I suppose). After removing it from SO, the URL still stayed on Worldbuilding. Hoping this with logs and such is sufficient info to repro and address.